# WooCommerce REST API - Get Orders using after/before parameters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the WooCommerce REST API (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) and are able to download Customers, Orders etc successfully. I would now like to just download a list of Orders between 2 dates - I can see in the docs for Orders the following parameters:

```
after   string  Limit response to resources published after a given ISO8601 compliant date.
before  string  Limit response to resources published before a given ISO8601 compliant date.
```

I've modified the URL for the request to this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?after=2016-08-05&before=2016-08-06&page=1
```

but I'm getting a 400 error with this response:

```
{
  "code": "rest_invalid_param", 
  "data": {
    "params": {
      "after": "The date you provided is invalid.", 
      "before": "The date you provided is invalid."
    }, 
    "status": 400
  }, 
  "message": "Invalid parameter(s): after, before"
}
```

The 2 dates are valid ISO8601 compliant dates as far as I can tell. Can't find an example of how this request should look so not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out you need to also specify the time, e.g.

```
after=2016-11-20T13:57:31.2311892-04:00
```

Comment: Can you make it work with a positive timezone, like +01:00?